# Calculate number of months from 02 different years in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im calculating number of months in two different years.That means if i select date filter from 2020 jan 1st to todate i need to show 2020 has 12 months and 2021 has 02 months todate from january.i want to show 02 cards seperately to show months.is there a way to do this? I tries Datediff. But it shows months count form 2020 to todate. Can someone help me to get this?

Thank

Comment: Do you have 2 separate date filter for start and end date? Or always start date to to date? What do you mean by 2 separate cards? What if years belongs to 3 different years?

Comment: Im having a date filter from 2020 to 2021 todate.so in here i need to get 12 months for 2020 and 02 months for 2021 to date.i can get the full month count from min date to todate.but i need to get count of months for 02 different years seperately

Comment: Can you show your presentation of selecting dates in report?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a table containing only the 'Date'[Date] column, like generated by

```
Date = CALENDAR("2019-01-01", "2021-12-31")
```

you can write two measures, one to get the months of the last year in the selection and of the previous one

```
# Months = 
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR( MAX( 'Date'[Date] ) ) 
VAR CurrentYearDates = FILTER( 'Date', YEAR( 'Date'[Date] ) = CurrentYear )
VAR Months = SELECTCOLUMNS( CurrentYearDates, "Month", MONTH( 'Date'[Date] ) )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS( DISTINCT ( Months ) )


# Months PY = 
VAR PY = YEAR( MAX( 'Date'[Date] ) ) - 1
VAR PYDates = FILTER( 'Date', YEAR( 'Date'[Date] ) = PY )
VAR Months = SELECTCOLUMNS( PYDates, "Month", MONTH( 'Date'[Date] ) )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS( DISTINCT ( Months ) )
```

this allows to assign a measure per card

[image: power BI visuals]

This could be simplified with a Date table with Year and Month

```
Date = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR ( "2019-01-01", "2021-12-31" ),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month", MONTH ( [Date] )
)

# Months = 
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR( MAX( 'Date'[Date] ) ) 
RETURN
    CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Date'[Month] ), 'Date'[Year] = CurrentYear )


# Months PY = 
VAR PY  = YEAR( MAX( 'Date'[Date] ) ) - 1
RETURN
    CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Date'[Month] ), 'Date'[Year] = PY )
```